# python3: do a for loop once more when looped over the whole file

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, eof

Following code fails if the is a End of file instead an emptyline. It is for a simple parser, which looks for a `=` sign and then return the content as soon as an empty line is read

```
def readFile():
    keyFlag=False
    for line in open(AAA,"r").readlines():
       if "=" in line: keyFlag=True
       if key.Flag: content+=line
       if line.ispace(): return content
```

The  problem is that when the file end comes then the for loop is stopped. Is there an elegant way to loop once more, other than inserting a flag?

Comment: could use the number of lines in content to do this

Comment: @Chris_Rands: I modified the question, as it will be a primitve parser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `return` outside of the loop, then just `break` inside the loop if the line is blank.

```
def readFile():
    flag = False
    content = ""
    for line in open(AAA):
       if '=' in line:
           flag = True
       if flag:
           content += line
       if line.isspace(): 
           break
    return content
```

Comment: Agreed. And while this may be turse as an example, a production version should probably do `content = []` then `content.append(line)` and finally `return ''.join(content)` for performance reasons. Also, it should do `with open(AAA, "r") as f:`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a while loop:

```
data = open(AAA,"r").readlines()
i = 0
while i < len(data):
   content+= data[i]
   i+=1
return content
```